# SPS 2010 Prerequisite installer keep downloaded files

Tags: files, sharepoint-2010, prerequisites

In SharePoint 2010 there is a prerequisite installer. There are options to install the prerequisites from a local source.

That's great, but is it also possible to tell the prerequitiinstaller to download the files and keep them in its prerequisite directory?

I don't want to download the files manually as it is a big pain in the back to get these files from the Microsoft website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting this I realized you wanted to get the prereqinstaller to do the download for you.  However if you download them once yourself you can simply store the 6 files in your own directory.

just went thru this myself last week- I found this on the net somewhere and it worked:

1.) Place the downloaded files into a directory.  For my example: C:\sp

2.) Run the following command via command prompt within the root directory of the install media:

PreRequisiteInstaller.exe /SQLnCli:C:\sp\sqlncli.msi /ChartControl:C:\sp\MSChart.exe 
/PowerShell:C:\sp\PowerShell_Setup_amd64.msi /Sync:C:\sp\Synchronization.msi 
/IDFX:C:\sp\MicrosoftGenevaFramework.amd64.msi /adomd:C:\sp\SQLSERVER2008_ASADOMD10.msi

the prereqs are:

sqlclient,powershell, syncframework, mschart, geneva framework, adomd.net

links:
[SQLClient](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123718)

[SyncFramework](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=141237)

[MSChart](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=122517)

[PowerShell](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/0/E/D0E6D2C1-2593-4017-B26D-7375BC9263D5/PowerShell_Setup_amd64.msi)

[Geneva Framework](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/D/F3D66A7E-C974-4A60-B7A5-382A61EB7BC6/MicrosoftGenevaFramework.amd64.msi)

[Microsoft ADOMD.NET](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/D/0/AD021EF1-9CBC-4D11-AB51-6A65019D4706/SQLSERVER2008_ASADOMD10.msi)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links ;) but I am curious if it isn't possible to let prerequisitinstaller.exe do the job (or somehow find out where it stores the files an snatch them)

Comment: @elhombre: you could probably use procmon to figure out where the files are going (I'm guessing in your users Temp folder) - but what is the purpose of that given the information @Jim has outlined above?